# Should I create two seperate frontends - desktop and mobile?

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, architecture

We're facing a new react project, which should run on desktop and mobile. Some of the desktop features won't be available on mobile.

We're debating whether we should create two separate front-ends or a single, responsive front-end.

Could you elaborate on the pros and cons of each approach? Which one would you use instead of me?

Comment: This is too broad/opinionated a question for Stack Overflow, I think.

Comment: This is a very broad question, what I would say is facebook made react and react-native for a reason you should probably use those to create your apps (aka two different applications). nice thing about react-native is you get to actually have an app instead of a website to go to on mobile, and you have native support and access which can be really useful. There is a lot of overlap between both react and react-native. a lot can be shared between the two if done right just a different rendering element set

Comment: I'd agree with you @JohnRuddell, that it's worth building a native app using react-native, as well as a web-app using react. But, if I understand the OP, correctly, Aviran is asking at this stage if it is right to build one React web-app for larger screens and one React web-app for smaller screens.

Comment: @Rounin if that is truly what the OP is asking then I'd agree with your answer :) I dont think i have ever seen a use case so great as to make two websites one for mobile and one for desktop.. that just wouldn't make any sense. but when it comes to a mobile app native is the way to go (webviews inside a mobile app is pretty terrible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I create two separate frontends - desktop and mobile?

**No.**

For a well-written web-app, a single, manageable codebase ought to suffice for *all* hardware:

- Desktops
- Laptops
- Tablets
- Touchphones

Build a single, responsive front-end. Where features on larger screens and smaller screens don't match exactly, use a combination of:

- graceful degradation
- progressive enhancement

This is simply best-practice, efficient, future-proofed project management, using **DRY** (Don't Repeat Yourself) as a philosophy to work by. [1]

---

1. Rather than **WET** (Write Everything Twice).

Answer (score 1):

IMHO one can reach 90%-99% with a single site / PWA depending on the application. To reach 100% a company has to invest heavily. So, I think for many companies this boils down to:

- Do we have the resources?
- Do we want to pay the price (initial invest)?
- Do we want to pay the price (maintanance, new features, etc)

My recommendation is to start simply with a web app. Make a good separation of concerns at the backend (split api/business logic from presentation layer etc). If you are successful and want to reach the 100%, invest in further options.

There are many examples (news sites for instance), which abandon the approach of having two separate implementations.